# New to WPF. Form not displaying correctly

Tags: wpf, layout, gridview

I am very new to WPF and cannot seem to get my form to display correctly. I expected to have 6 rows. The first three should have buttons in them and the last 3 contain further grids. I was following code from an NHibernate ebook but it does not seem to display correctly. Could someone take a look at this code and suggest any possible errors:

```
<av:Window x:Class="Chapter2.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Title="Product Inventory" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="493" d:DesignWidth="566" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<av:Grid>
    <av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <av:RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <av:RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <av:RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <av:RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <av:RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <av:RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <av:Button x:Name="btnCreateDatabase" Content="Create Database" Click="BtnCreateSessionFactoryClick"/>
    <av:Button x:Name="btnCreateSessionFactory" Content="Create Session Factory" Click="BtnCreateSessionFactoryClick" av:Grid.Row="1"/>
    <av:Button x:Name="btnCreateSession" Content="Create Session" Click="BtnCreateSessionClick" av:Grid.Row="2" />
    <av:Grid x:Name = "CategoryGrid" av:Grid.Row="3" Margin="0 10 0 0">
        <av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <av:ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <av:ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <av:RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <av:RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <av:RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <av:TextBlock Text="Category Name:"/>
        <av:TextBlock Text="Category Description:" av:Grid.Row="1"/>
        <av:TextBox x:Name="txtCategoryName" av:Grid.Column="1"/>
        <av:TextBox x:Name="txtCategoryDescription" av:Grid.Row="1" av:Grid.Column="1"/>
        <av:Button x:Name="btnAddCategory" Content="Add Category" av:Grid.Row="2" Click="BtnAddCategoryClick" />
    </av:Grid>
    <av:Grid x:Name = "ProductGrid" Margin="1,0,-1,131" av:Grid.Row="4">
        <av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <av:ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <av:ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <av:RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <av:RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <av:RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <av:TextBlock Text="Category Name:"/>
        <av:TextBlock Text="Category Description:" av:Grid.Row="1"/>
        <av:TextBox x:Name="txtProductName" av:Grid.Column="1"/>
        <av:TextBox x:Name="txtProductDescription" av:Grid.Row="1" av:Grid.Column="1"/>
        <av:Button x:Name="btnAddProduct" Content="Add Product" av:Grid.Row="2" Click="BtnAddCategoryClick" />
    </av:Grid>
    <av:Grid x:Name = "LoadCategoryGrid" av:Grid.Row="5" Margin="1,0,-1,0" >
        <av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <av:ColumnDefinition Width="278"/>
            <av:ColumnDefinition Width="265"/>
        </av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <av:RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <av:Button x:Name="btnLoadCategories" Content="Load Categories"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="BtnLoadCategoriesClick" Margin="0,188,186,0" />
        <av:ListBox x:Name="lstCategories"  Margin="52,188,-55,-10" av:Grid.Column="1" />
    </av:Grid>
</av:Grid>
```

[image: Window]

Comment: Can you clarify "off centre" with a screenshot and perhaps a rendition of how you want it to appear? Walls of XAML text hurt my eyes ;-)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I was working on putting up. I have fixed the off centre issue. That was the grid being wider than the main form I think. I will get a picture up showing what it currently looks like.

Comment: I have added an image now. You can see the 3 buttons and one grid are visible but the last two grids are not. Sorry for the poor pic but I only had paint and it wont let me crop for some daft reason

Comment: The bottom grid specifies a RowSpan of 2 for the ListBox but only has 1 row defined.

Comment: No, that would be `Grid.ColumnSpan`. Other than that and the double `Grid.Row="5"` definition as stated in the answer below, I can't see much wrong with that without actually trying to run it myself.

Comment: Sorry your right. My code in front of me seems to have changed. Maybe I reset or something. I will change the code on here to reflect it. The problems still remain.

Comment: Have you tried removing the margins to see how stuff lays out by default?

Comment: That fixed it. I dont know how those margins got there in the first place. Thank you for helping. Being new to wpf it would have taken me ages to think of doing that. If you want to add an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I've created an answer to save future visitors from trawling through the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the stray double definition of `Grid.Row="5"` and `Grid.RowSpan="2"` with only one row defined, both of which you have now fixed, the only other code that would affect the positioning is all the spurious `Margin` values.

Other than that the XAML looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

The last grid overlap the one at row 5, the lines:

```
<av:Grid x:Name = "ProductGrid" Margin="-1,2,1,130" av:Grid.Row="5">
<av:Grid x:Name = "LoadCategoryGrid" av:Grid.Row="5" Margin="3,73,-3,128" >
```

place the two grid at the same grid row, look at the `av:Grid.Row` attached property with the same value. To move one of them in a free place one has to be changed with: `av:Grid.Row="4"`

Comment: I have fixed that issue but there has been no change in the appearance of the window.